# Authoritative Name Server Registration w/out IPv6

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm considering adding a 3rd authoritative Name Server to our hosting infrastructure.

However, while the first 2 DNS servers have both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address, the 3rd DNS server would only have an IPv6 address.

Given how DNS works, I don't suspect this would be a problem (if someone / some computer tried to access the 3rd DNS server via IPv6, it would just attempt to contact one of the other 2 name servers).

However, I wanted to get other members' feedback on whether or not this is actually a good idea. Would it be better to stick with 2 DNS servers, both of which support IPv6, or would it be better to add a 3rd DNS server that only supports IPv4?

Note that the reason I'm thinking about adding another DNS server is not due to load or heavy DNS traffic on the existing 2 servers. Instead, I'd like to get at least 1 DNS server off of our primary hardware provider's network for redundancy purposes.

Its extremely unlikely that our hardware provider's (Linode) entire system would go belly up, and unlikely that both of our DNS servers would go down since they are in 2 separate datacenters in 2 different parts of the States, but still, the theory remains that it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A third server that supports IPv4 only is perfectly fine, *provided* that the existing IPv6 DNS servers are not physically located at the same location. (i.e. they should be georedundant)

The standards don't require DNS servers at different physical locations simply to avoid the problem of physical servers going down or losing their links. You need georedundant *network paths* so that a temporary routing problem to one of your locations doesn't result in all of your DNS servers being unreachable. (no matter how brief: even less than a minute is bad)

It's a given that consistency in design is always a preference, but multiple physical locations *and* potential network paths are only a good thing when it comes to extending your DNS cluster. Or at least until you have [so many NS records](https://serverfault.com/a/597631/152073) that your `ADDITIONAL` section exceeds 512 UDP bytes and things start breaking...